# Mocking asyncio Python requests responses

Tags: python, python-requests, pytest, python-asyncio

I'm trying to test an async function in Python 3.6.8 along with:

```
asyncio==3.4.3
requests==2.22.0
responses==0.10.6
pytest==4.6.3
pytest-asyncio==0.10.0
```

I'm requesting a number of URLs at the same time, but pared down my function looks somewhat like:

```
async def check_urls_tester(url: str) -> int:
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        futures = [loop.run_in_executor(executor, requests.head, url)]

        response = await asyncio.gather(*futures, return_exceptions=True)
        return int(response[0].status_code)
```

My attempt at a test looks like:

```
@responses.activate
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_check_urls_async(self):
    responses.add(responses.HEAD, "https://www.google.com", status=404)
    resp = await check_urls_tester("https://www.google.com")
    assert resp == 404
```

I expect my function to return a 404 since I am using [responses](https://github.com/getsentry/responses) to mock out requests, but this returns a 200. I can successfully use responses with non-async functions, but not with this async function.

What step am I missing here?

Comment: Do you know there's https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/?

Comment: AFAIK `responses` doesn't support `asyncio`; there is `aresponses`, but w/o decorator. Best replacement for the async use case is indeed `aiohttp`.

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but if we're talking about options to requests, there's also [httpx](https://www.python-httpx.org/) (requests async equivalent) and [respx](https://lundberg.github.io/respx/) (responses async equivalent).